# dos etiquetas <script> vs <script type = 'text/javascript'>

Tags: javascript

Que diferencia entre:

```
<script type="text/javascript">.....</script>
```

o

```
<script>.....</script>
```

Por favor explicame para entender claro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A partir de HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type), no es necesario especificar el lenguaje del script, por defecto es text/javascript.

> The type attribute gives the language of the script or format of the data. If the attribute is present, its value must be a valid MIME type. The charset parameter must not be specified. The default, which is used if the attribute is absent, is "text/javascript".

así que

```
<script></script>
```

es interpretado por el navegador como

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

además de javascript algunos navegadores soportan otros lenguajes, como lo indican en [este post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434378/what-client-side-web-scripting-languages-are-there-other-than-javascript-and-vbs)

> - JavaScript / JScript (which is ubiquitous)
> - VBScript (IE 10 and lower only)
> - PerlScript (IE with a plugin from ActiveState only)
> - Dart (in a nonstandard build of Chromium) which is not intended for production use.

Respondiendo a la pregunta principal

> Que diferencia entre:
>
> `<script type="text/javascript">.....</script>`
>
> o
>
> `<script>.....</script>`

Ninguna, no hay ninguna diferencia desde HTML5, aunque siempre se recomienda utilizar `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` por compatibilidad hacia atrás (backward compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

`<script></script>` ha sido introducido en html5

Así podriamos omitir el tipo que usa por defecto, que es `text/javascript`, pero antes de html5 se usaba `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` ya que no había un tipo por defecto

Así que, si estas usando html5, utiliza `<script>`, sino utiliza `<script type="text/javascript">`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Aqui estas usando la etiqueta `<scrip>` junto a uno de sus atributos `type`
Lo que le estas diciendo al navegador es que va a haber un script y le estas especificando que es de tipo javascript.

Como mencionó alguien, ahora en html5 ya no es necesario por que el navegador automaticamente detecta de que tipo es. Asi que es lo mismo usar:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> alert("Hola Mundo") </script>
```

O

```
        <script> alert("Hola Mundo") </script>
```